# exception handling on ls

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, ls

I want to do an exception handling on ls command.

here is my code:

```
ls -l -S "$@" || echo "contains error options"
```

however, the output of code will return the standard ls error message and the echo part together when I run the script like ./test.sh -dsflwljrew(I want it to get error message)

I want the script will just print the echo part when the argument has invalid ls options. 
how can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

nvm...I found out a solution by using 2>/dev/null to redirect the error message.

```
ls -l -S "$@" 2>/dev/null || echo "contains error options"
```

This will print:

```
contains error options
```

Comment: This will print your eror message for whatever error occured. It will not just check the options. Thus it will be misleading. For example hiding erros like `No such file or directory` or `Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

You may do

```
 ls -l -S "$@" 2>/dev/null || echo "contains error options"
```

By the way if the script arguments are not supposed to be `ls` options, then do

```
ls -l -S -- "$@" 2>/dev/null || echo "contains error options"
```

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here